# Can you hide a column based on a cell value in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm very new to Using Google sheets and especially the script part of it.

I am currently making an F12021 Score Board thingy, Basically allowing me to choose different races in order to see how different drivers could have won the championship if certain races weren't included, This is obviously just something fun and not anything serious. It's a bit like the Youtube Channel Chainbear, he does this sort of stuff all the time.

I need to hide column C if C1=False on the third sheet (D2021Graph), and when C1=True I would like them unhidden and hide column D when D1=false and so on. The C1 and D1 are based on checkboxes on the first sheet(RaceResults2021) This is so the graph which plots all the values on that sheet can avoid certain columns in case I want to deselect them.

Heres a copy of the Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12b-lbkBaigX6UGJB6URouHP2hawUuH_3_LqQZCyW1MI/edit?usp=sharing

All help is appreciated and if you need more information let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and solution:

If I understand you correctly, you want to hide/unhide a column from `D2021Graph` whenever the checkbox in the corresponding column in `RaceResults2021` is checked or unchecked.

If that's the case, you could use a simple [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger to do the following:

- Using the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), check that the edited cell is one of the checkboxes (checking that it's the correct sheet, row and column).
- Considering that Grand Prixes start at column 3 in the `graph` sheet and at column 8 in the `race results` sheet, and that they are in the same order in both sheets, find out with column in `graph` corresponds to the edited checkbox from `race results`.
- Get the value of the corresponding cell, and use [hideColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex) or [showColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex) depending on whether the value is the boolean `false` or not.

#### Code snippet:

```
var firstColResults = 8; // Grand Prix start at column H in RaceResults2021
var rowResults = 2;
var firstColGraph = 3; // Grand Prix start at column C in D2021Graph
var rowGraph = 1;
var resultsSheetName = "RaceResults2021";
var graphSheetName = "D2021Graph";

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var range = e.range;
  var activeSheet = range.getSheet();  
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  if(resultsSheetName == activeSheet.getName() && editedRow === rowResults && editedColumn >= firstColResults) {
    var graphSheet = ss.getSheetByName(graphSheetName);
    var colGraph = editedColumn + firstColGraph - firstColResults;
    var value = graphSheet.getRange(rowGraph, colGraph).getValue();
    if (value === false) graphSheet.hideColumns(colGraph);
    else graphSheet.showColumns(colGraph);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, theres only a slight issue with your code, The checkboxes are on row 5 and not 2 but that was an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const shts=["Sheet1","Sheet2"];//Change the sheet names to whatever you want
  const cols=[3,4];
  if(shts.indexOf(sh.getName())!=-1 && e.range.rowStart==1) {
    if(cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)!=-1) {
      if(e.value=="TRUE")sh.hideColumns(e.range.columnStart);
      //if(e.value=="FALSE")sh.showColumns(e.range.columnStart);
    }
  }
}
```

Your idea comes up a little short on the planning ahead part because if you have the column hidden then how are you going to uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: I think you missunderstood a little bit, the columns with checkboxes arent supposed to hide, instead the column which it correlates to on the sheet "D2021graph" is supposed to hide.

Comment: Oh so you want the columns in one sheet to hide the same columns in the other sheet is that right?

Comment: Sort of, but i have already got it to work but thanks anyways! I basically wanted Column C to hide in the sheet "D2021Graph" when the box at H5 on sheet "RaceResults2021" was unticked.

Comment: Well I’m glad you were able to figure it out for yourself that’s always the best solution perhaps you should consider answering questions on track overflow